# image not displaying in my form in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am having issues displaying image on the website i am developing. It a website that users can change their profile picture, as well as their basic profile information. bellow is my sample code.

**profile.php**

```
      <?php 
                    $studpix=$row_rsp['pix'];
                    $propix='<img class=
   "profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" src="...
    /Student /imageupload/blank.png"
                             alt="profile picture">';

                      if($propix!=NULL)
                      {
                    $propix='<img class="profile-user-img 
    img-responsive img-circle" src="Student/imageupload/'.$studpix.'"
                             alt="profile picture">';

                        };
                        $profile_pic_btn = 
'<a href="#"   onclick="clicked(\'avatar_form\')">  Profile pics</a>';
$avatar_form  = '<form id="avatar_form" 
enctype="multipart/form-data"   method="post" action="photoup.php">';
$avatar_form .=   '<h4>Change your picture</h4>';
$avatar_form .=   '<input type="file" name="avatar" required>';
$avatar_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
$avatar_form .= '</form>';
                        ?>
  <?php echo $propix?><?
   php echo $avatar_form?><?php   echo $profile_pic_btn;?> 


  //other codes goes here
```

imageupload.php

```
               <?php 
if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]
["tmp_name"] != ""){
$fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
$kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileExt = end($kaboom);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
    echo "ERROR: That image has no dimensions";
    exit(); 
}
$db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999).".".$fileExt;
if($fileSize > 1048576) {
    echo "ERROR: Your image file was larger than 1mb";
    exit(); 
} else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
    echo "ERROR: Your image file was not jpg, gif or png type";
    exit();
} else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
    echo "ERROR: An unknown error occurred";
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT pix FROM studentdetails WHERE email='%s'";
$query = mysqli_query($myconn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$avatar = $row[0];
if($avatar != ""){
    $picurl = "../Student/imageupload/$avatar"; 
    if (file_exists($picurl)) { unlink($picurl); }
}
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file(
 $fileTmpLoc, "../Student  /imageupload       /$db_file_name");
if ($moveResult != true) {
    echo "ERROR: File upload failed";
    exit();
}
include_once("../image_resize.php");
$target_file = "../Student/imageupload/$db_file_name";
$resized_file = "../Student/imageupload/$db_file_name";
$wmax = 200;
$hmax = 300;
img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
$sql = "UPDATE studendetails SET pix='%s' WHERE email='%s' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($myconn, $sql);
mysqli_close($myconn);
header("location: profile.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your script have access to upload files to that directory? And on which platform does the server run?

Comment: yes...it uploads file to the directory....but it is not displaying on the form.

Comment: There isn't enough information to go on here. Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Can you view the picture from the absolute URL directly? If yes, then there must be a problem in your PHP / HTML

Comment: the "profile.php" is the php file that calls the imageupload.php and displays it on the form. the file is stored on the above dir but not displaying on the form.

Comment: @emekamba Is `imageupload.php` located in the same directory as `profile.php`?

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory...

Comment: You upload the file to `../Student  /imageupload       /$db_file_name`, which, uploads to the parent folder, and also contains whitespace within the filename, which it shouldn't. But you reference it in `profile.php` as `src="Student/imageupload/'.$studpix.'"`,, without the `../`. Does this help?

Comment: @michiel have tried yur suggestion, but still facing the same issue. another observation is that, it is not uploading to the data base table "studentdetails"

Comment: @emekamba That could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to debug your code step by step.**

**1.** Check whether the file gets uploaded correctly and to the correct folder.

**2.** Check whether the data is updated correctly in the database.

**3.** Try to open the file by URL directly in the browser.

**4.** Check whether your HTML code is outputted correctly on the webpage and debug the outputted source code.

**5.** Make sure that your HTML code works properly.

*There may be more steps to take, but this might give you some direction.*

Comment: Still experiencing the same issue, after going through your steps. pls do u know another way of uploading a profile pic? ur help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you complete all the steps? Did you experience any issues? You should be able to manage it with this answer.

Comment: Have tried starting everything afresh,but still the same issue.

Comment: Please can u post a working sample of this? will appreciate it. thank in advance

Comment: No, I'm sorry. This question is too broad to post a working sample. I have given you the information to proceed. If you have specific questions, I can answer them.